# Create complex model for booking application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an application to rent soccer fields with ASP .NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework. Regrettably, I have no idea of how to solve the problem of prices of the fields on different days and times of the week. I made a Model (I show that below) but I'm not sure if that is the best way to solve the problem.
Let me explain a little more about the application. These are the most relevant entities for the question:

SportCenter

```
public class SportCenter
{
    public int SportCenterID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OpeningHour> OpeningHours { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

}
```

Booking

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    public string StartHour { get; set; }

    public string EndHour { get; set; }

    public int SportCenterID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int FieldID { get; set; }

    public virtual SportCenter SportCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }

}
```

Field and Price

```
public class Field
{
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public int PriceID { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public string StartingHour { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

To be more clear, every field has different prices for each day and hour of the week when the sport center is open. Thats will generate a table like this one (I have a nice image but I can't attach because my reputation)

```
---------- Mon - Tue - Wed - Thur - Fri - Sat - Sun
-----------------------------------------------------
13:00 --- Close - Close - Close - Close - Close - Close
14:00 --- Close - Close - Close - Close - Close - Close 
15:00 --- $400 - $50 - $23 - $22 - $90 - $90 - $90
16:00 --- $300 - $70 - $34 - $34 - $90 - $90 - $90
17:00 --- $240 - $60 - $53 - $55 - $90 - $90 - $90
18:00 --- $320 - $78 - $85 - $96 - $40 - $90 - $90
```

I can reach this point and maybe is an accepted solution but I don't have a clue of how can I represent this in a .cshtml page, and let the user view and edit the content. So, to summarize, the questions are two:

- Is this the best solution (or at least an accepted one) for the model structure problem with the prices?
- How can I represent this information in a browser and let the user view and edit the prices for every day and hour of the week.

Thank you!

PD: Sorry for my english

Edit: 
Now I can upload, thanks ;)

[image]

Edit2:

This is what I have actually for the frontend. Same as the other case, don't know if this is the best way to represent the information to the user or I'm missing something.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>MON</th>
            <th>TUE</th>
            <th>WED</th>
            <th>THU</th>
            <th>FRI</th>
            <th>SAY</th>
            <th>SUN</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <td><input value="300" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input value="300" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would gravitate more to a distinction between day and price. So, have a day model with a list of prices. Field 1 --- m Day 1 --- m Price. Then you could have a model of type Field in which you can loop through the enumerations of days and prices in days.

Comment: So you have problem in your Data Models or View Models of Presentation ?

Comment: @persianDeveloper I want to know if this is a good way for structure my data model and , on the other hand, whats the best way to show the information to the user (.cshtml code).

Comment: @Adimeus Could be better, but I think that model doesn't represent the real world. I still prefer the actual model

Comment: There are bunch of examples of asp.net mvc complex models out there that show you how to use them in Views. (please do not use .cshtml ) and it depends on your business needs and what you gonna do with your view.